# VBA to add row below total row that calculates percentage of total

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of data that calculates totals for each change in grouping for 3 categories. I need to insert a row below the totals row to calculate a percentage of total for the same three fields. There are varying amounts of rows for each change in grouping.

I have used the following code to insert the row:

```vb
Sub insert percent row()
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("Q1:Q100")
  If c.Value Like "*Total*" Then
    c.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
  End If
Next c

End Sub
```

I'm stuck on what to do next.

My total is in column Q and my three calculation cells are in columns Y, Z and AA. I need to insert Y/Y+Z+AA, Z/Y+Z+AA, AA/Y+Z+AA below their totals and format as a percent. Ideally I'd like it to look like this:

```
    A        Q               Y    Z    AA
    Item 1   Group 1         1
    Item 2   Group 1         1
    Item 3   Group 1              2
    Item 4   Group 1              2
    Item 5   Group 1                   4
             Group 1 Total   2    4    4
             Group 1 Percent 20%  40%  40%
```

Comment: You can use a simple formula for that, and use `NumberFormat` to format as a percentage. What specific problem are you having? You can even use the macro recorder to generate the code for you.

Comment: I thought a macro might be easier considering some groupings have 1 item where others have 30. How would you go about adding a formula to the blank rows? I tried filtering but adding in the blank row breaks my filter. I've found other code that I've tried to tweak to suit my needs but it's written for a total column versus a total row.

Comment: As I said, the macro recorder will generate the code for you. Start the recorder, go through to build the formula, stop the recorder, click the Macros button, and edit the macro to see the code. That gives you the generated code that you can modify however you'd like. Sum() works for a column with some empty cells, so you can sum the column directly to get your Total row, and then calculate the percentages using those for the Percentage row (again, with a simple formula).

Comment: I think our wires are crossed. The Group 1 percent line does not exist but the total line does. I'm trying to insert a row below the total line, name the cell in Q based on the group number and then calculate and format the percents in Y/Z/AA. Each of these worksheets can have hundreds of groups with several items. I'll try recording the macro in the morning and report back.

Comment: That doesn't change anything I've said, other than to remove the need to use Sum() to get the Total row. Once again, use the macro recorder to generate the code that adds the formula, which gives you the template code that you can modify to suit your needs to put in the new row(s) as often and wherever needed. It's actually simpler now that the Total already exists, because you can easily reference the row immediately above the one you're inserting to plug into the formula via your code.

Comment: I'll see if I can simplify. Make a copy of your workbook. Open that copy in Excel. Start the macro recorder. Go through the steps to insert a row (right-click on the number on the line with *Total*, choose Insert Row, etc.). Continue through the steps of building the formula you want for column Q in that new row. Stop the recorder, and view the generated source. You have a template for the entire operation upto that formula being generated. Copy that code, open Notepad, and paste it in. You now have a template to use to write your code in your original workbook, modified as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It assumes that your Total is in column X.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim EmptyFields As Integer
    Dim MyRow As Integer
    Dim GrandTotal As Integer

    Dim Percent1, Percent2, Percent3 As Double
    EmptyFields = 0
    MyRow = 1

    ' if 3 continuous cells are empty, we should assume that the dataset is over
    Do While EmptyFields < 3

        Range("X" & MyRow).Select

        ' if we see Total in column X, we should get grand total of that row
        ' and caculate percentages. Then, we add a new row below it
        ' and store the percentages in the new row
        If LCase(Range("X" & MyRow).Text) = "total" Then
            GrandTotal = Range("Y" & MyRow).Value + Range("Z" & MyRow).Value + Range("AA" & MyRow).Value
            Percent1 = Round(Range("Y" & MyRow).Value * 100 / GrandTotal)
            Percent2 = Round(Range("Z" & MyRow).Value * 100 / GrandTotal)
            Percent3 = Round(Range("AA" & MyRow).Value * 100 / GrandTotal)

            Range("X" & MyRow + 1).Select
            Selection.EntireRow.Insert , copyorigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Range("X" & MyRow + 1).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Percent"
            Range("Y" & MyRow + 1).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Str(Percent1) & "%"
            Range("Z" & MyRow + 1).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Str(Percent2) & "%"
            Range("AA" & MyRow + 1).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Str(Percent3) & "%"

            EmptyFields = 0
            MyRow = MyRow + 1

        ' if cell is empty, increment empty fields variable
        ElseIf Len(Trim(Range("X" & MyRow).Text)) = 0 Then
            EmptyFields = EmptyFields + 1
        Else
            EmptyFields = 0
        End If

        MyRow = MyRow + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Based on the updated requirement, try this code:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim EmptyFields, MyRow, GrandTotal As Integer
    Dim Percent1, Percent2, Percent3 As Double
    Dim TotalLabel As String
    EmptyFields = 0
    MyRow = 1

    ' if 3 continuous cells are empty, we should assume that the dataset is over
    Do While EmptyFields < 3

        Range("Q" & MyRow).Select
        TotalLabel = Range("Q" & MyRow).Text

        ' if we see Total in column X, we should get grand total of that row
        ' and caculate percentages. Then, we add a new row below it
        ' and store the percentages in the new row
        If InStr(LCase(TotalLabel), "total") > 0 Then
            GrandTotal = Range("Y" & MyRow).Value + Range("Z" & MyRow).Value + Range("AA" & MyRow).Value
            Percent1 = Round(Range("Y" & MyRow).Value * 100 / GrandTotal)
            Percent2 = Round(Range("Z" & MyRow).Value * 100 / GrandTotal)
            Percent3 = Round(Range("AA" & MyRow).Value * 100 / GrandTotal)

            Range("Q" & MyRow + 1).Select
            Selection.EntireRow.Insert , copyorigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Range("Q" & MyRow + 1).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Replace(LCase(TotalLabel), "total", "Percent")
            Range("Y" & MyRow + 1).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Str(Percent1) & "%"
            Range("Z" & MyRow + 1).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Str(Percent2) & "%"
            Range("AA" & MyRow + 1).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Str(Percent3) & "%"

            EmptyFields = 0
            MyRow = MyRow + 1

        ' if cell is empty, increment empty fields variable
        ElseIf Len(Trim(Range("Q" & MyRow).Text)) = 0 Then
            EmptyFields = EmptyFields + 1
        Else
            EmptyFields = 0
        End If

        MyRow = MyRow + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It looks exactly like what I'm looking for. I adjusted all of your "X"s to reflect "Q"s (that's where my "Total" is). When I run it, it does nothing and jumps to 3 cells below my last "Total." Any suggestions? I'll keep tinkering in the mean time.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot with me of how your data looks?

Comment: I ended up reverting to what I know (formulas) and solved my problem. I'd still like to get this in vba form but until then, I'll use my formula solution. Here's a link for what it looks like after my solution: https://ibb.co/HXVNwFM Thank you very much for your time and attention.

Comment: Change `If LCase(Range("X" & MyRow).Text) = "total" then` to `If InStr( LCase(Range("X" & MyRow).Text, "total") > 0 then` and then change all the "X" to "Q". See if that helps.

Comment: I updated the code and get a Compile Error: Expected: List Separator and it highlights the "Then."

Comment: My bad, use `If InStr( LCase(Range("X" & MyRow).Text), "total") > 0`. I missed a closing bracket.

Comment: I had fixed that and removed the extra space before LCase and I still get the error. Based on my digging, it looks like InStr needs two arguments which I don't think this has. But I could be totally wrong bc this is not my area of expertise.

Comment: Can you type out the instr statement you have typed in your code? On my latest comment I have 2 arguments to instr

Comment: If InStr(LCase(Range("Q" & MyRow).Text), "total") > 0 Then
When I do it this way, I get a run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Try the updated code. When you have errors, I'd like to see your code and data.

Comment: I'll try it again and see what it does. Give me a day or two to send results.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I tried the updated code and now get Run-time error '6': Overflow

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not getting my desired result via VBA. I ran the code I originally posted to add a blank row after my "Total" row. Then I did the following with formulas:

1. Add in columns after Q, Y, Z, AA
2. In column R add formula
   =IF(Q2="",OFFSET(Q2,-2,0)&" Percent","No")
3. In column AA add formula
   =TEXT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Percent",R2)),Z1/(Z1+AB1+AD1),"No"),"#0%")
4. In column AC add formula
   =TEXT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Percent",R2)),AB1/(Z1+AB1+AD1),"No"),"#0%")
5. In column AE add formula
   =TEXT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Percent",R2)),AD1/(Z1+AB1+AD1),"No"),"#0%")
6. Convert all formulas to values
7. Filter to cells that contain "Percent" in column R
8. Drag and drop "Percent" cells into blank cells in column Q
9. Filter out "No" cells in column AA
10. Drag and drop percentage cells from AA into blank cells in column Z
11. Drag and drop percentage cells from AC into blank cells in column AB
12. Drag and drop percentage cells  from AD into blank cells in column AD
13. Delete columns R, AA, AC, AE